# The best way (pattern) to execute something while exception is thown

Tags: c#, exception, for-loop, try-catch

Below is a code showing tries to encapsulate a logic to re-run something while an exception is being catch.

Does exist patterns or something else to do that ? Or what improvements would you suggest to that code ?

```
    public static void DoWhileFailing(int triesAmount, int pauseAmongTries, Action codeToTryRun) {
        bool passed = false;
        Exception lastException = null;

        for (int i = 0; !passed && i < triesAmount; i++) {
            try {
                if (i > 0) {
                    Thread.Sleep(pauseAmongTries);
                }
                codeToTryRun();
                passed = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                lastException = e;
            }
        }

        if (!passed && lastException != null) {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Something failed more than {0} times. That is the last exception catched.", triesAmount), lastException);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you have `passed = true` you could just `return` and then at the end you wouldn't need to check it, just throw an exception.  Some people really hate multiple exit points, others don't.  Here I think multiple exit points makes sense.

Comment: The "catch(Exception e)" **is wronge** you should be catching the expection you expect to be able to recover from and checking it's details.   E.g. a database exception checking that it is failing due to a deadlock.   Otherwise this code is very like what we have apart from clearing the connection cache when we get an exception, as SqlConnection will reuse a broken connection.

Comment: retry some action you mean?

Comment: @IanRingrose, maybe just having a generic parameter that specifies which exception to catch before re-run, could be better. Similar to juharr answer, although he suggests to "deliver" the exception to the caller which could via delegate to check the exception.

Comment: @Luciano, the problem I found is that database deadlocks and cluster fallovers throw the same exception class as "real" database errors.   So the exception message text and/or error numbers needed to be processed.

Comment: @IanRingrose: Sure. Unfortunately some .net exceptions inherit COM and WIN32 concepts where error code or properties should be analysed instead of just the Exception itself, thus splitting it in a kind of sub-exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code to do basically the same thing.  It also lets you specifiy the type of Exception to catch and a `Func` that determines if the current iteration should throw the exception or continue retrying.

```
public static void RetryBeforeThrow<T>(
    this Action action, 
    Func<T, int, bool> shouldThrow, 
    int waitTime) where T : Exception
{
    if (action == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    if (shouldThrow == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("shouldThrow");
    if (waitTime <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Should be greater than zero.", "waitTime");
    int tries = 0;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return;
        }
        catch (T ex)
        {
            if (shouldThrow(ex, ++tries))
                throw;
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
Action a = () => 
    { 
        //do stuff 
    };
a.RetryBeforeThrow<Exception>((e, i) => i >= 5, 1000);
```

And you can specify any exception type and you can check the exception in the `Func` to determine if it is an exception that you want to throw or to continue to retry.  This gives you the ability to throw your own exceptions in your `Action` that will stop the retries from occurring.

Comment: I wouldn't use extension method to do that, but the delegate approach to expose the exception is a nice solution. I'll adopt it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would re-write this to eliminate a few variables, but in general your code is OK:

```
public static void DoWhileFailing(int triesAmount, int pauseAmongTries, Action codeToTryRun) {
    if (triesAmount<= 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("triesAmount");
    }
    Exception ex = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < triesAmount; i++) {
        try {
            codeToTryRun();
            return;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ex = e;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(pauseAmongTries);
    }
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Something failed more than {0} times. That is the last exception catched.", triesAmount, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the code, I would just question your assumptions.

A couple of problems that I see:

- Clients need to understand the failure modes of the called action to choose the right parameters.
- The action could fail intermittently, which is a capacity killer. Code like this can't scale well.
- Clients can wait for an indeterminate amount of time for the action to complete.
- All exceptions but the last will be swallowed, which could hide important diagnostic information.

Depending on your needs, your code might suffice, but for a more robust way to encapsulate an unreliable resource, take a look at the [circuit breaker](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2008/05/the-circuit-breaker) pattern.